# Android-webservice integration

Tags: android-intent

I have developed one android application but now i want to connect my application with sql server,how to connect with sql server is there any direct way otherwise through webservices only,if the way is only webservices then how to do that one plz help me some steps of procedure how to connect with webservices.

Comment: I'd personally recommend you to use REST webService like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44302488/4116560)

Answer (score 0):

May be you can get help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11953342/how-to-list-posts-from-database-in-android-using-listactivity/11954854#11954854). You can implement JSON based approach in any of your preferred technology e.g. PHP, Java, .Net etc. Then you just need to make simple `GET/POST` calls to the server and parse the returned JSON in Android using classes in package `org.json.*` from Android library itself. So, No other dependencies. I prefer this JSON approach because of no dependency and simpler implementation than consuming SOAP based web services.